# AS3 addEventListener to movieclip inside another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, movieclip

So, I have a movieclip named "LoginScreen" with a instance inside called "confirmbutton".

I want to add the LoginScreen to stage and set a event listener to the button inside it, but I keep getting an error.

This is my code:

```
var LoginScreen:loginscreen = new loginscreen;
LoginScreen.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
LoginScreen.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
addChild(LoginScreen);

LoginScreen.confirmbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);

function test(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("Sup?");
}
```

I get the error:

```
Symbol 'LoginScreen'    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: confirmbutton.
```

I'm pretty sure it exists and its named properly (has that exact name without caps), so I'm guessing its probably a scope problem.

Comment: Are you sure that *loginscreen* is MovieClip? Maybe it is *Graphic* or *Button*?

Comment: Both are MovieClips. I only do movieclips for basically everything, for extra flexibility with actionscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a helper gettter function for getting the inner MovieClip. So where you defined the LoginScreen class put a simple getter function like this one:

```
public function get ConfirmButton():MovieClip { return this.getChildByName("confirmButton") as MovieClip; }
```

Then you can access that MovieClip from the LoginScreen object like this:

```
LoginScreen.ConfirmButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Renamed the button to "confirmButton" (capital "B") and started working. I guess the problem was that the "confirmbutton" was also the AS Linkage of the movieclip.

Comment: That's why you MUST always name linkages and classes with First capital letter.

Comment: Whoops. I usually do them exactly the other way around. AS linkage in small letters, and MovieClips in Capitalized first letters.